# Am I using AC relays correctly?

Tags: relay, solid-state-relay

My original question was put on hold because a number of people found it confusing. Drew figured it out, however, and set me down the right path with relays (not diodes). There is still one issue outstanding, so I'm updating my question based on my newfound understanding of relays.

THE BASICS

- I'm wiring a vintage traffic light for novelty use in my home.
- I purchased a [controller](https://www.trafficlights.com/controllers/n10-4-way-traffic-light-controller/) that sends load to the G-Y-R lights in
  sequence, same as you see on the street.
- I'm trying to customize the behavior of the lights a bit.

Instead of:

> Phase 1 (G)
>
> Phase 2 (Y)
>
> Phase 3 (R)

I want this:

> Phase 1 (G and Y simultaneously)
>
> Phase 2 (Y and R simultaneously)
>
> Phase 3 (R)

The solution that Drew provided — a relay — works perfectly for Phase 3. Meaning when R gets juice from the controller, the current can't also advance to the Y through the relay.

Originally I didn't describe the desired output of each phase because I didn't think it necessary. However, now I see that without two additional relays, during Phase 1 (G and Y), current will advance to the R through the relay. And during Phase 2 (Y and R), current will advance to the G through the push-in wire connector.

**QUESTION:** even if that last paragraph isn't clear, as illustrated below will the three relays succeed in channeling the current to only the colors indicated during the active phase?

[image: Wiring diagram with relays in situ.]

Comment: That's a nasty schematic.

Comment: Apart from unique "farmhouse" and other "off grid" DC installations, "household current" is AC meaning that a diode will not help you.

Comment: What IS happening in Phase 3. Also what does DIP switch 4 do vs what it is supposed to do?  ( red overlap enable)

Comment: Do the coloured  LED  agree with the Steeetlights?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 They do in the UK!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, assuming we're dealing with AC here...

As others have mentioned, you're probably going to want to use relays for this. AC-IN/AC-OUT Solid State Relays are cheap and simple to use. For example this one: https://smile.amazon.com/SSR-25AA-80-250V-24V-380V-Machinery-Control/dp/B01MZ2B0LA

Just hook up a relay in parallel with your controller, so that either the controller or the relay can turn on the RED light. Then hook up the input of the relay to your yellow light signal.

See terrible paint edit below:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, Drew! I had doubts in the back of my mind that diodes were the appropriate solution, but they seemed like my only hope.